# how to use scroll view in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollview, react-native

i am trying to create a shopping app for a client and i wanted to add the scrolling property to the cart page of the app so i used the

```
`scrollview`
```

property, immediately i added the `scrollview` and reloaded the app everything scattered.

here is the original page without the `scrollveiw`

[image]

and here is the page with the `scrollview`

[image]

i fixed this problem after some research by adding this `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}`to the `scrollview`, after that i added more content to the page but it did not scroll, i don't know know why, maybe i might be doing something wrong here is the code for the page

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.page}>
       <Cartheader gotocart={gotocart} gotohome={gotohome} />
       <View style={{justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center'}}>
       <View style = {styles.up}>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.back} onPress={gtoback}>
            <Image style={styles.arrowb} source={require('../resources/arrowback.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.overall}>
            <View style = {styles.title}><Text style={{fontSize:RFPercentage(5),fontWeight:'bold',marginLeft: '4%',}}>Cart</Text></View>

            <View style = {styles.cartitems}>
                <View style ={styles.details}>
                    <View style={styles.details1}><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Item</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.details2}><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Quantity</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.details3}><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Item Total</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.details4}><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Remove</Text></View>
                </View>
                <View style ={styles.real}>
                <View style={styles.real1}>
                <Image style={styles.dem} source={require('../resources/comfortable-seats-in-empty-corporate-meeting-office-for-presentation-JCC1N0.jpg')} />
                <View style={styles.descrip}>
                    <View><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(2.5)}}>A/c Chairs</Text></View>
                    <View><Text style={{fontSize:RFPercentage(1.25), color:'#40b9e9'}}>N 400.00 NGN</Text></View>
                </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.real2}>
                    <View style={{width:'50%',height:'60%',justifyContent:'space-around',alignItems:'center'}}><Text style = {{fontSize:RFPercentage(2.5)}}>2</Text></View>
                    <View style={{width:'50%',height:'60%',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image style={styles.arrowc} source={require('../resources/arrowback.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity  >
            <Image style={styles.arrowd} source={require('../resources/arrowback.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.real3}><Text style={{color:'#40b9e9',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.5)}}>N 800.00 NGN</Text></View>
                <View style={styles.real4}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.x}>
                        <Text style={{color:'#fff',fontSize:RFPercentage(2.5),marginTop:-2}}>x</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            {/* ///////////////////////////////////// */}
            <View style={styles.payment}>
                <View style={{justifyContent:'space-around',height:'100%',width:'57%'}}>
                    <View style={styles.pay}><Image style={styles.radio} source={require('../resources/radio.png')} />
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:5,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Pay On Delivery</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.pay}><Image style={styles.radio} source={require('../resources/radio.png')} />
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:5,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Paystack(subscription)</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.pay}><Image style={styles.radio} source={require('../resources/radio.png')} />
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:5,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>Qucikteller(Master Card/Verve)</Text></View>
                </View>
                <View style={{justifyContent:'space-around',height:'100%',width:'41%'}}>
                    <View style = {styles.total}><Text style={styles.bold}>Sub Total:   </Text><Text style={{color:'#40b9e9',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>N 7400.00</Text></View>
                    <View style = {styles.total}><Text style={styles.bold}>Shipping:   </Text><Text style={{color:'#40b9e9',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>N 0.00</Text></View>
                    <View style = {styles.total}><Text style={styles.bold}>Garnd Total:   </Text><Text style={{color:'#40b9e9',fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>N 7400.00</Text></View>

                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.terms}>
            <Image style={styles.checkbox} source={require('../resources/check.png')} />
            <Text style= {{fontSize:RFPercentage(1.8)}}>I Have Read And i Agree To The Terms & Conditions</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttons}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{width:'70%',height:'40%',backgroundColor:'darkblue',justifyContent:'space-around',alignItems:'center',}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'#fff',textAlign:'center',fontSize:RFPercentage(3.2), fontWeight:'bold'}}>Proceed To Checkout</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{width:'70%',height:'40%',}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'darkblue',textAlign:'center',fontSize:RFPercentage(3.2), fontWeight:'bold'}} onPress={gotohome}>Back To Shop</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{width:'30%',backgroundColor:'red'}}></View>
        </View>

       </View>
       </View>
    </View></ScrollView>
```

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try copying what they do in the documentation: [scrollView Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)

Here is the code from their snack :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 42,
  },
});
```

The point you should note is that they are using `flex:1` in the `style` attribute, not on `contentContainerStyle`.

Comment: it just takes scatters the page again

Comment: sorry it actually works all i needed to do was to remove the flex:1 i added to the main view and give it a height, thankss!!!